# "maven archetype: generate" command: how many archetype files will it list?

Tags: maven

I am a new learner of maven, and I was browsing this tutorial: [Jenkov's maven tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-archetypes.html) in which it shows that "maven archetype: generate" will list over 1300 maven archetypes. And [another tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-project-with-maven-template/) also showed the result as follow:

> $ mvn archetype:generate
>
> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO] [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] [INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @
>   standalone-pom >>> [INFO] [INFO] <<<
>   maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
>   [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @
>   standalone-pom --- [INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
>   [INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart
>   (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
>
> Choose archetype:
>
> 311: remote -> jboss:mobicents-ra-archetype (An archetype for slee
>   resource adaptor.) //...
>
> 314: remote -> ml.rugal.archetype:springmvc-spring-hibernate (A pretty
>   useful JavaEE application archetype based on springmvc spring and
>   hibernate)
>
> //... 486: remote ->
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-j2ee-simple (An archetype
>   which contains a simplifed sample J2EE application.) 487: remote ->
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-marmalade-mojo (-) 488:
>   remote -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-mojo (An
>   archetype which contains a sample a sample Maven plugin.) 489: remote
>   -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-plugin (An archetype which contains a sample Maven plugin.) 491: remote ->
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-portlet (An archetype
>   which contains a sample JSR-268 Portlet.) 492: remote ->
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-profiles (-) 493: remote
>   -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart (An archetype which contains a sample Maven project.) //...

However, when I tried this command, the infomation that I got is :

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli)
>
> > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>> [INFO]  [INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources
> >     @ standalone-pom <<< [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> >     maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom
> >     --- [INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode [WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
> >     [INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart
> >     (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0) Choose
> >     archetype: 1: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-archetype (An archetype
> >     which contains a sample archetype.) 2: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-j2ee-simple (An archetype
> >     which contains a simplifed sample J2EE application.) 3: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-plugin (An archetype which
> >     contains a sample Maven plugin.) 4: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-plugin-site (An archetype
> >     which contains a sample Maven plugin site.
> >           This archetype can be layered upon an existing Maven plugin project.) 5: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-portlet (An archetype
> >     which contains a sample JSR-268 Portlet.) 6: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-profiles () 7: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart (An archetype
> >     which contains a sample Maven project.) 8: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-site (An archetype which
> >     contains a sample Maven site which demonstrates
> >           some of the supported document types like APT, XDoc, and FML and demonstrates how
> >           to i18n your site. This archetype can be layered upon an existing Maven project.) 9: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-site-simple (An archetype
> >     which contains a sample Maven site.) 10: internal ->
> >     org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp (An archetype which
> >     contains a sample Maven Webapp project.) Choose a number or apply
> >     filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 7

there are only 10 archetypes and all of them are internal.

I am confused about this and may I know if there's  anything wrong with my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally managed to locate and use a remote archetype I was looking for. The "solution" is more a workaround, but it did the job.

Before you do anything crawl your local maven repo with `mvn archetype:crawl`. This will find every downloaded archetype artifact and adds it to your `archetype-catalog.xml`. If that didn't worked try following:

1. locate the archetype artifact (search in mvnrepository.com)
2. download the archetype artifact with `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version`
3. crawl your local mvn repository for archetypes with `mvn archetype:crawl`
4. the archetype should now be listed in `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml` or `/path/to/local/mvn/repo/archetype-catalog.xml`
5. execute `mvn archetype:generate` you should now have a lot more available archetypes
6. (bonus) if you want to search for a specific archetype in the given list, search for the artifactId, you could also use the `-Dfilter=artifactId` flag but that didn't worked for me